# Blank Values in Excel File From CSV (not just rows)

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm currently opening CSV files in Excel with multiple columns, where values will only appear if a number changes. For example, the data may ACTUALLY be: 90,90,90,90,91. But it will only appear as 90,,,,91. I'd really like the values in between to be filled with 90s. Is there anyway python could help with this? I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a short solution (one liner for transforming `['90','','','','','91']` into `['90','90','90','90','90','91']`):

```
 import csv
 spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv', 'rb'))
 for row in spamReader:
      a = map(lambda i : reduce(lambda y, z: z != "" and z or y, row[:i]), range(1,len(row)+1))
      print ",".join(a)
```

Comment: Quick questions...when I try putting the format in a CSV file:

    import csv
    with open ('eggs.csv', "w") as f:
         csv.writer(f).writerows(",".join(a))

It isn't able to do this properly, how should I change this?

Answer (score 2):

One technique to is use a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function that takes a row of data and return the row with filled values as needed with `yield`.

### Code

```
def fill_row(row):
    last_val = None
    for col in row:
        if(col != '' and col is not None):
            last_val = col
        yield last_val


inp_row = [90,'','','','',91,'',92]
filled_row = [x for x in fill_row(inp_row)]

print(filled_row)
```

### Output

[90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 92]

### Alternative solution

The purely list based solution looks like this

```
def build_filled_row(row):
    last_val = None
    new_row = []
    for col in row:
        if(col != '' and col is not None):
            last_val = col
        new_row.append(last_val)
    return new_row

alternate_filled_row = build_filled_row(inp_row)

print(alternate_filled_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the missing values when you open the CSV with wordpad? If so, then Python or any other scripting language should see them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this entirely in excel:

Select column (or whatever range you're working with), then go to Edit>Go To  (Ctrl+G) and click Special. 
Check Blanks & click OK.
This will select only the empty cells within the list. 
Now type the = key, then up arrow and ctrl-enter.

This will put a formula in every blank cell to equal the cell above it.  You could then copy ^ paste values only to get rid of the formulas.