# Fill empty cells in excel sheet (or SQLite) with the value of nearest filled cell above

Tags: sql, excel, fill, cells

I have faced an issue when sending queries to a SQLite database.

The problem is that the database (which origins from an excel sheet) has empty cells where there should be values, values that are given from a cell above, in the same column.

**In other words, the maker of the excel sheet has left the cells in he same column blank if the value does not change. I actually need values in those cells!**

I can not do this manually due to the size of the sheet/db, is there a way to do this programmaticly?

I would really prefer a sql-query way, if there is any!

Best wishes,
Tor

Comment: Is this an android question? Please consider removing the tag if it does not apply.

Comment: Yes and no. The database applies to an android application, although it is not an android specific question. Tag removed.

Comment: If dataentry was forgotten, how do you know what was above is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What SQLite command can replicate empty fields from a prior row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70853327/what-sqlite-command-can-replicate-empty-fields-from-a-prior-row)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in excel. I answered a similar question here:

[Blank Values in Excel File From CSV (not just rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570157/blank-values-in-excel-file-from-csv-not-just-rows/9570477#9570477)

> > You can also do this entirely in excel:
>
> Select column (or whatever range you're working with), then go to
>   Edit>Go To (Ctrl+G) and click Special. Check Blanks & click OK. This
>   will select only the empty cells within the list. Now type the = key,
>   then up arrow and ctrl-enter.
>
> This will put a formula in every blank cell to equal the cell above
>   it. You could then copy ^ paste values only to get rid of the
>   formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You query the whole db, keep the original sort order and then iterate over each row. If something is empty update it with the value from above.

Edit: you might do it with something similar to this here:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("myDb.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
Cursor c = db.query("table", null, null, null, null, null, "the column that defines the sort order");
if (c != null) {
    int columnCount = c.getColumnCount();
    String[] lastValues = new String[columnCount];
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            String value = c.getString(i);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                // if that happens on first column you are screwed anyways.
                cv.put(c.getColumnName(i), lastValues[i]);
            } else {
                lastValues[i] = value;
            }
            // we need to save some id here
        }
        if (cv.size() > 0) {
            // use the id here
            db.update("table", cv, "column=?", new String[] { "id" });
        }
    }
    c.close();
}
```

But i'd suggest you use Excel to fix the database. That's easier and you don't need to understand above code.

Comment: And how do i perform that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

A similar way to the one proposed by @maneesha would be to filter by blank cells, then write the "equals to the upper cell" formula and then clear the filter.

But I think @maneeshas' solution is cooler.