# What SQLite command can replicate empty fields from a prior row?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, where-clause, correlated-subquery

I am importing some data into sqlite, where some columns use an empty value to indicate that the value is the same as the previous row's value.

How can I accomplish this purely in SQLite SQL?  I have a row number that indicates ordering.

For example, after importing and processing `with-blank`, it should appear to be identical to importing `non-blank`.

```
$ cat with-blank.csv 
n,x,y
1,aaa,foo
2,,bar
3,,baz
4,bbb,able
5,,baker

cat non-blank.csv
n,x,y
1,aaa,foo
2,aaa,bar
3,aaa,baz
4,bbb,able
5,bbb,baker
```

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import with-blank.csv t
```

Note: Not a duplicate of [Fill empty cells in excel sheet (or SQLite) with the value of nearest filled cell above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673257/fill-empty-cells-in-excel-sheet-or-sqlite-with-the-value-of-nearest-filled-cel/9673631), which includes Excel as a potential solution.

I'm looking for the Pure SQL command which can do this.  I can of course do this as a preprocessing step prior to importing into SQLite, but I would like to learn what commands, if any, can do this in SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have imported the table, you can update the empty column values by using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET x = (
  SELECT t2.x 
  FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.n < t1.n AND COALESCE(t2.x, '') <> '' 
  ORDER BY t2.n DESC LIMIT 1
)
WHERE COALESCE(t1.x, '') = '';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=42721e8bd9a0e1f70ca645b466a973f0).